# How to retrieve error when launching sqlcmd from C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to run a stored procedure from a C# application.

I use the following code to do so:

```
Process sqlcmdCall = new Process();
sqlcmdCall.StartInfo.FileName = "sqlcmd.exe";
sqlcmdCall.StartInfo.Arguments = "-S localhost\\SQLEXPRESS -d some_db -Q \":EXIT(sp_test)\""
sqlcmdCall.Start();
sqlcmdCall.WaitForExit();
```

From the sqlcmdCall object after the call completes, I currently get an ExitCode of -100 for success and of 1 for failure (i.e. missing parameter, stored proc does not exist, etc...).

How can I customize these return codes?

H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to call a stored procedure from c# you would want to use ADO.Net instead of the calling sqlcmd via the command line.  Look at `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace.

Once you are calling the stored procedure via `SqlCommand` you will be able to catch an exception raised by the stored procedure as well we reading the return value of the procedure if you need to.

Comment: This answer side steps the question of using sqlcmd.  Sqlcmd is the only options sometimes such as customer providing a script loaded with GO statements- ADO.Net cannot handle those.

Answer (score 2):

I have a small VB.Net app that executes system commands like that. To capture error or success conditions I define regular expressions to match the error text output from the command and I capture the output like this:

```
        myprocess.Start()
        procReader = myprocess.StandardOutput()

        While (Not procReader.EndOfStream)
           procLine = procReader.ReadLine()

           If (MatchesRegEx(errRegEx, procLine)) Then
              writeDebug("Error reg ex: [" + errorRegEx + "] has matched: [" + procLine + "] setting hasError to true.")

              Me.hasError = True
           End If

           writeLog(procLine)
        End While

        procReader.Close()

        myprocess.WaitForExit(CInt(waitTime))
```

That way I can capture specific errors and also log all the output from the command in case I run across an unexpected error.

Answer (score 0):

Even with windows authentication you can still use `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` to execute, and you don't have to re-invent the wheel for exception handling.

A simple connection configuration and a single `SqlCommand` can execute it without issue.